# How to enter a TAB character in the Notes field in KeePass 2.x?

Tags: keepass

Is there any way to easily enter a tab character in the "Notes" text-field in KeePass 2.x?  In that particular field I use it to format information (so it lines up).

```
Some title:           text
Some other title:     text
And another:          text
```

The Tab key will move focus to a different control (as will Win+Tab on this machine) and Ctrl+Tab will switch tabs at the top of the form.

I *can* copy a tab character from another document (like Notepad) and paste it in that field, and it works as expected - but that's cumbersome.  Does anyone know of a direct-input method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this in version 1.14 of KeePass under Windows XP SP3:

Alt+0009 (numbers entered on the numeric keypad)

And voila!  A tab character was entered into the editor, per your request.  :)

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the answer, except I just bought a Dell XPS 1640 and ingenious designers decided to not include any NumPad keys on it (not even with a Fn-key combination like my old Inspiron).  Short of any other suggestions, maybe I'll have to figure out how to emulate the NumPad keys with AutoHotKey or something to do just that.   Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I use LifeHacker's "Texter" program to do text replacement.  Thought I'd try to have it replace a custom hotstring with emulated keystrokes for Alt+0009 on the keypad - {Alt down}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad9}{Alt up} - but no luck.  Works in Notepad, but in KeePass it has the same effect as pressing the tab key.

Comment: Ah, upon further inspection - it DOES add the tab character, but also moves to the next control.  So I just added +{TAB} to the emulated keystrokes above and it works. Thanks for the help!

Texter Hotstring Replacement (script):
{Alt down}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad9}{Alt up}+{TAB}

Comment: Man, what an unfortunately convoluted solution for such a simple thing.  Well, you got it working, and that's what counts.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Just saw an answer for this in a KeePass bug report. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> inserts a tab in richtext controls.

Source: http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/feature-requests/1138/